# Fatal Error C1083: Cannot Open Include file: 'tiffio.h': No such file or directory VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++

I got this error when I tried to compile an application that includes the `tiffio.h` header.

For the record, the `tiffio.h` is located at:

`C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\include`

I *have* set that directory to be included in the 'Projects' and 'Solution' Visual C++ directories, as shown in the image located here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Options dialog you have in the image - change the "Show directories for" from "Executable Files" to "Include files" and then add the include path there.