# Compiling pymc/matplotlib on Python with MS Visual Studio 2008 fails

Tags: python, compilation, matplotlib, freetype, pymc

Despite numerous attempts to install pymc with no luck -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878430/installing-pymc-then-matplotlib-win7-64-continues-to-fail-despite-workarounds -- I came across another SO post ([Building lxml for Python 2.7 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047542/building-lxml-for-python-2-7-on-windows/5122521#5122521)) explaining that I need to install MS Visual Studio 2008 to get this to compile, as I am using Python 2.7.3 on Win7-64, installed as part of Python(x,y).

When I now use `python setup.py install`, I don't get a "can't find vcvarsall.bat" error, but I get the following. Prior to running the following, I added `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\bin` to the end of my PATH statement.

Any ideas on what this means/what I need to do next, as I have no idea how to unpick it?

## Update 12-Nov-2013

I've now tried to install matplotlib via the available binary and freetype from Sourceforge. Neither seems to improve the situation. Any furter suggestions on what to try?

BTW the *real* goal is to install pymc -- however, there seems to be a dependency on matplotlib, where the following originates from.

```
    ft2font.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
c:\users\dantehman\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-sdaatv\matplotlib-1.3.1\src\ft
2font.h(16) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such
 file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 284, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you use the pre-installed binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ ?  The problem is that matplotlib requires the freetype headers, which you have not installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib Build Problem: Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762292/matplotlib-build-problem-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ft2build-h)

Comment: I'm unable to install PYMC on a fresh install of pythonxy.  easy_install will complete, but the package cannot be imported.  pip install pymc fails with fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mingw32.lib'