# Error in installing Matplotlib : fatal error C1083

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I am relatively new to Python coding and want to learn about statistics and data management in Python. For this I would like to install Matplotlib, which is giving me some issues.

I see other people having this issue, but I have not fully understood how to fix it.

To install i use

```
pip install matplotlib
```

**I have the following specs installed**

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8
- Microsoft Studio 2019

The first error i got was to install Microsoft Studio, so I did that. 
I have also attempted to update pip

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB 
 matplotlib: yes [3.1.1] 
 python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]] 
 platform: yes [win32] 

...

 checkdep_freetype2.c
    src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib Build Problem: Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762292/matplotlib-build-problem-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ft2build-h)

Comment: The problem you face comes from a failed building process of matplotlib. However, usually, matplotlib will have wheels available on pip for most major platforms, so I wonder why it's still trying to compile anything. Does the message in the command line tell anything about which version it is trying to build?

Comment: Hi IMportanceOfBeingErnest


Do you mean something like this?

 BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC
                      v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
        platform: yes [win32]


I have actually just installed Python two days ago and just tried to install MatPlotLib today. I installed Numpy without any issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have python 3.8, not python 3.7.
But there are **no python 3.8 wheels available for matplotlib 3.1.1** on pypi. So best remove python 3.8 completely and install python 3.7.
When you then run `python -m pip install matplotlib` it will install the compiled version from the wheels, so there is no need to compile anything yourself or have Microsoft Studio available.

Comment: Perfect thank you that solved it. I guess the Matplotlib community have not yet updated to fit with Python 3.8 then?

Comment: @user12239916 Yes, python 3.8 was only released some days ago, while matplotlib 3.1.1 is from July this year. The next matplotlib release should in principle be compatible with python 3.8; but as usual, there might still be slight problems. Unless you really need python 3.8, just wait for half a year until everything is settled.

Comment: Thank you!! you saved me. I couldn't figure out why it kept breaking lol

Comment: Note that matplotlib has been available for python 3.8 (in wheel format) for several months now.

Answer (score 5):

After spending a lot of time on the issue, this helped me to solve it:

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib==3.2.0rc1
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI: the matplotlib website [installation instructions](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) has some info on installing from source.

For Windows it states setting include path and link path:

```
set CL=/IC:\directory\containing\ft2build.h ...
set LINK=/LIBPATH:C:\directory\containing\freetype.lib ...
```

Comment: You can find all include files here: https://github.com/ubawurinna/freetype-windows-binaries

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you may install matplotlib on Windows using the 'Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages' with `pip install <downloaded_filename>`.

Tested on Python 3.8, Windows 10 and matplotlib-3.2

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib

Comment: Excellent suggestion, it does the trick for me, too, and there is no need for fiddling aroind with any further configurations or path definitions or whatever. Good work!