# Matplotlib: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip, python-packaging

I want to install the `matplotlib` package for Python with `pip install matplotlib` in the command prompt but suddenly the lines get red and the next error appears:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\pol\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Pol\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v44y041t\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Pol\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v44y041t\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Pol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d5re6a86\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`

I'm using Windows and my Python version is 3.8.0. I have already tried `python -m pip install matplotlib` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems a problem with pip. Try the following:                                    pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel

Comment: This gives the following error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for install`

Comment: There are no wheels for matplotlib 3.1.1 on python 3.8. Unless you want to build matplotlib from source, use python 3.7 instead. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58457893/4124317).

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest.  I erased my post. I suspected you downvoted me, my recommendation was to solve a pip problem. There was no matplotlib mention.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I changed to 3.7.5 and it did work this time.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Came across a solution (which, as I understand, is quite recent):

```
python -m pip install -U matplotlib==3.2.0rc1
```

Explanation:

> Since there are no wheels available, installing matplotlib 3.1.1 on
>   python 3.8 requires to build it from source. This process may turn out
>   to be a little cumbersome. So for anyone having problems with that,
>   either
>
> Install matplotlib 3.1.1 on python 3.7 Wait for matplotlib 3.2.0 to be
>   released with the respective wheels for python 3.8

Also, someone pointed to wheels stored here:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib

But I haven't tried those myself.

Source: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15041

Comment: Followed your step, a very good explanation but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

**pip install --pre -U scikit-learn**
this command is work for me
I have found because this error come for the duplication of same libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your command prompt with administrator privileges

If the problem further persists try reinstalling pip

Comment: This is not a problem with pip, It is a problem with Python 3.'o' version