# Current Matplotlib version compatible with Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried pip installing Matplotlib to python 3.8 and was faced will a wall of errors, is this a me problem or is the current Matplotlib version not compatible with 3.8? Will supply screenshots of the errors if requested.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: There are [no wheels for 3.8 yet](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/#files), so your chances are not great. See also https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15295#issuecomment-532892311

Comment: Matplotlib 3.1.1 itself is compatible with python 3.8. However, installing it would mean to build it from source. This would require a correctly set compiler and all dependencies being linkable - so it's not easy. Also see [error-in-installing-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455888/error-in-installing-matplotlib-fatal-error-c1083/58457893#58457893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest (stable) version 3.1.1, looks like it is for Python 3.7.

https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/3.1.1/#files

On the other hand, I would recommend Anaconda, makes package and module managing really simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Will move to Anaconda for matplotlib.