# cannot install/update package "rgl": installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status in Windows 10

Tags: r, windows-10, rgl

I am trying to update my rgl from 0.103.5 to 0.104.16 version. When I ran updates, I get the following error message:

```
    install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary   source needs_compilation
rgl 0.103.5 0.104.16              TRUE

installing the source package ‘rgl’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.104.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2832742 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'rgl' ...
** package 'rgl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Configuring for R 4+ including OpenGL
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -Iext -Iext/ftgl -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -DHAVE_PNG_H -DHAVE_FREETYPE -Iext         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c ABCLineSet.cpp -o ABCLineSet.o
"C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -Iext -Iext/ftgl -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -DHAVE_PNG_H -DHAVE_FREETYPE -Iext         -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c BBoxDeco.cpp -o BBoxDeco.o
In file included from glgui.h:10,
                 from BBoxDeco.cpp:6:
ext/ftgl/FTGL/ftgl.h:32:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ft2build.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:229: BBoxDeco.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgl'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/rgl'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

I read through the similar errors in stackoverflow but could not relate to my issue. It seems like the error can be traced back to OpenGL libraries, but, I am not sure how to troubleshoot that either. My understanding is that OpenGL comes with the OS, not as a sperate R library. Any suggestions/directions would be appreciated.

My sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13     magrittr_2.0.1      usethis_2.0.0       devtools_2.3.2      pkgload_1.1.0       githubinstall_0.2.2
 [7] R6_2.5.0            rlang_0.4.10        fansi_0.4.1         httr_1.4.2          tools_4.0.3         pkgbuild_1.2.0     
[13] data.table_1.13.6   xfun_0.20           sessioninfo_1.1.1   tinytex_0.28        cli_2.2.0           withr_2.3.0        
[19] remotes_2.2.0       ellipsis_0.3.1      assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.27       rprojroot_2.0.2     lifecycle_0.2.0    
[25] crayon_1.3.4        processx_3.4.5      purrr_0.3.4         callr_3.5.1         fs_1.5.0            ps_1.5.0           
[31] testthat_3.0.1      curl_4.3            memoise_1.1.0       glue_1.4.2          compiler_4.0.3      desc_1.2.0         
[37] prettyunits_1.1.1   jsonlite_1.7.2
```

Comment: Can [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534246/8245406) be of help?

Comment: @RuiBarradas so you think this is a 'FreeType' issue? if it were, wouldn't the error report refer to it? Besides, FreeType is optional for rgl, right?

Comment: The missing file comes with Free Type. The error report refers to the missing file, not to other files that come with Free Type. As for rgl, even if Free Type is optional, it may depend on some parts of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows build of `rgl` assumes that Freetype is available, and on your system it wasn't found.

The README for rgl says this:

> ### BUILDING ON MICROSOFT WINDOWS
>
> Install Rtools40 or newer.
>
> Install Freetype via
>
> pacman -S mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-freetype
>
> Then the usual R CMD INSTALL should work.

Alternatively, wait a few days, and the binary build should be available on CRAN.